# Google Maps API event.Pb - google change the name of this attribute

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have function to display window on map on event - click.

```
function showInfoWindow(event, link) {

    var scroll_top = $(".page-content").scrollTop();
    scroll_top = scroll_top - 80;
    var maxwi = $(window).width()-$('section.right').width() - 400;
    var width2;
if (event.Pb.pageX-20 > maxwi) {
    width2 = maxwi;
} else {
   width2 = event.Pb.pageX-20;
} 
    $("#popup-window").css({
        left:(width2)+"px",
        top:event.Pb.pageY+"px"
    }).show().addClass("loading");

    if(link) {
        $("#popup-window").find('a[name="zobacz_region"]').css("visibility", "visible");
    } else {
        $("#popup-window").find('a[name="zobacz_region"]').css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
}
```

But from time to time Google changes the name attribute Pb. 
How can this be solved?

Comment: Don't use undocumented properties.

Comment: The question is perfectly valid. @geocodezip, How about offering a solution along with your statement?